# varbinary or varchar to save AES encrypted data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, encryption, aes

I am using mysql and doing `AES_ENCRPYT` function to store some confidential data.So  the aes encrypted data storing field is `varchar` but when i insert some data and checked the database it seems like some wiered characters `i³£ÓXñÒOýpŠ`.. But when i changed the datatype to varbinary it appears as binary strings like `69b3a3d358f1d24ffd708a0cafdbdbd8`.I am using PHP and MYSQL

So my question is

Which datatype must be used to store aes encrypted data.? `varchar` or `varbinary`. And why.?

Also how to do a 256 byte aes encryption.?

I found some references **[here](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/)** stating that

**Why we used VARBINARY data type instead of VARCHAR:**

Because `AES_ENCRYPT()` encrypts a string and returns a binary string.

Comment: I always use var binary but char will work too. The data will be the same

Comment: Use binary type. Character types are subject to automating charactersets conversion, and you get a mess. For example, say data in the table is utf8, but client encoding is latin1, so MySql automatically converts each `é` character, represented in latin1 with hex E9, into c3 + a9 bytes in utf8, and stores these two bytes in the table. Then imagine that another client with encoding other than utf8 and latin1, which doesn't support `é` character, is trying do decrypt this string - and will get a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is a block cipher. Like all modern ciphers, AES - in any mode of operation such as CBC - only *accepts binary input and produces binary output*. This means that you have to perform [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) if when a string needs to be encrypted (e.g.  UTF-8). If you want to store the result *as text*, then you will have to use [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) (e.g base 64). Sometimes an implementation will already implicitly perform such encoding for you, but most of the time the user will have to do things himself.

The output of a cipher should be indistinguishable from random to an attacker. That means that there is no reason to store the output of AES in a string in a database; there are no operations that you can perform on the output besides decryption. If you need the ciphertext in text afterwards it is always possible convert the binary into a specific encoding afterwards. For normal *variable sized input*, `varbinary` would be best as the output size depends on the input size.

Only perform conversions to/from strings when you are required to do so.

---

Note that any encoding will expand the size of the ciphertext; base 64 uses 8 bits for each 6 bits of ciphertext (assuming ASCII compatible encoding), an expansion of 33%. So besides the fact that converting the data complicates the handling of the ciphertext, it will also increase the amount of storage required.